# In this case, is the compiler REALLY forcing me to use protected in a sealed class?

Tags: c#, inheritance

I can't think of an instance where a protected method should behave differently than a private method in a sealed class.

And yet:

```
public abstract class Base
{
    protected abstract void Foo();
}

public sealed class Derived : Base
{
    // Error CS0507: cannot change access modifiers when 
    // overriding 'protected' inherited member
    // public override void Foo() {}

    // Error CS0621: virtual or abstract members cannot be private
    // private override void Foo() {}

    // Compiles just fine.
    protected override void Foo() {} 
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The compiler isn't really "forcing" you to use protected. It was defined as protected, and will always be protected.

Even though it is in a sealed class, it is still not like a private member. If it were private, it would not be accessible from the base class.

Comment: As a further elaboration - the function was defined as protected in the base class, and derived classes cannot change this. `public override ...` would also be an error, so we can think of `protected override ...` as meaning "we are overriding the protected function defined in our base class" rather than "this function is protected, and also overrides the function of the same name in the base class". The latter interpretation seems to be what leads to the confusion. PS `override protected ...` also seems to be valid syntax, and helps emphasise the "correct" interpretation.

Answer (score 7):

In this case the compiler is faced with two seemingly odd choices

1. `private override` which is a bit non-sensical because virtual methods should never be private
2. `protected override` which is a bit non-sensical because protected methods should never be declared in a sealed type

Option #1 would be a bit odd because it's taking something which is an error everywhere else (private virtual) and making it a non-error in this specific case.  Option #2 though requires no special rules in the compiler.  It's always legal to declare a protected member in a sealed type just a bit odd to do so (issues a warning).  Hence the compiler has chosen the lesser of two odd syntaxes

Comment: Well, the compiler has no choice. The choice was made by the designers of C#, the authors of the C# Language Specification. And as Seattle Leonard said in his answer, the method can be called from inside the base class. A truely `private` method cannot be called from its base class. Note: You can introduce _new_ `protected` members in a `sealed` class, but that is not useful and gives a compiler _warning_ even if it is allowed.

Answer (score 2):

Like you said - there isn't any practical difference(unless you use reflection and check for access modifiers). But letting the compiler accept a private override in a sealed class will require making an exception in the overriding rules, which will introduce more complexity to the specification and the implementations - without any benefit. That's a good enough reason not to allow it.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot change the access level of a member when you override it.  If it's protected in the base class then it must be protected in the derived class.

Answer (score 0):

Because there is non such case and the VS has a rule [(CA1047)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182138.aspx) that warns you about it.

You should not do that. The reason why it is not a compile error, can be that it does not effect the code.

Comment: There is a difference between introducing a *new* `protected` member, and having a `protected` member through inheritance. In fact all classes, including `sealed` ones, have the `protected` method `MemberwiseClone`. It is non-virtual, so can't overridden, but it is still an inherited member of the class, and it is `protected`.

Comment: CA1047 warns you if you declare it, not if you inherit it.  I was thinking the same thing until I reread the spec.

Comment: @Zaaier, As Jeppe set the inheritance is different thing. You can not prevent anyhow do do anything for inherited elements. So the violation is to give protected not to have one. SO rules works as expected.